# Query working differently on different servers

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I've got a development server where my T-SQL code is working fine, but when I port it to my production server it's breaking. Here's the code:

```
DECLARE @ModelNumber AS int = 67787

;WITH UsedNumbers (clnum, clname1) AS
(
    SELECT 
        clnum COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS AS clnum, 
        clname1 COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS AS clname1 
    FROM
        ELITE.son_db.dbo.client
    WHERE 
        clnum NOT LIKE '%[A-Z]%'
),
OrderedNumbers (clnum, clnum_int, clname1) AS
(
    SELECT TOP 500000 
        clnum, CAST(clnum AS int) AS clnum_int, clname1 
    FROM 
        UsedNumbers
    WHERE 
        CAST(clnum AS int) >= @ModelNumber
    ORDER BY 
        clnum
)
SELECT TOP 1 
    REPLACE(STR(previd + 1, 6), ' ', '0') AS previd
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         clnum_int, LAG(clnum_int) OVER (ORDER BY clnum) previd
     FROM 
         OrderedNumbers) q
WHERE 
    previd <> clnum_int - 1
ORDER BY 
    clnum_int
```

When I run this code on the development server, it returns results without a problem. When I run it on the production server, I get this error:

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
>   Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '57235A' to data type int.

On both servers, if I replace the last SELECT statement with:

```
SELECT * 
FROM UsedNumbers 
WHERE clnum LIKE '57%'
```

I get no results on the development server or the production server, so I'm totally confused by the error message.

Side points: ELITE in the initial SELECT statement refers to linked servers found on both servers. Both linked servers point to the same database, i.e., there are not development and production versions pointed to by the linked servers. 67787 is a seed value that was given to me by the end users; it has no significance to the program other than they want to find the next number after that number.

Can anyone suggest what could be going on here?

Comment: What does `SELECT * FROM ELITE.son_db.dbo.client WHERE clnum LIKE '57%'` yield?

Comment: 6 rows. The clnums which are returned are 57235A through 57235F. However, they're filtered out of UsedNumbers, and therefore are not in OrderedNumbers.

Comment: That is what should be happening, but if the query plan attempts some evaluation of OrderedNumbers before applying the filtered UsedNumbers, then there will be a conversion issue. If you change the final SELECT to simply `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM OrderedNumbers` do you get the same error?

Comment: If you compare the query plan for each, are they different between the two servers?

Comment: When I do a SELECT COUNT(*) FROM OrderedNumbers, I get the same error message. I'll check the query plans. Thanks!

Comment: Actually, I don't get a query plan on the production server. I guess it bombs before SQL Server even creates a query plan. :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160548/discussion-between-forty3-and-melanie).

Comment: Did you doublecheck if UsedNumbers doesn't contain any alphanumeric values?

Comment: Additionally, you might want to try the following: WHERE clnum NOT LIKE '%[A-Z][a-z]%' - there might be a chance, that your source system is case sensitive (guess thats why you collate to case insesitive)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously the error generated here when you are casting

```
OrderedNumbers (clnum, clnum_int, clname1)
AS
(
    SELECT TOP 500000 clnum, CAST(clnum AS int) AS clnum_int, clname1 
    FROM UsedNumbers
    WHERE CAST(clnum AS int) >= @ModelNumber
    ORDER BY clnum
)
```

some how clnum leaks VARCHARs and CAST() to int breaks. Production can execute cte in parallel. Try to use ISNUMERIC ( clnum ) = 1

```
OrderedNumbers (clnum, clnum_int, clname1)
    AS
    (
        SELECT TOP 500000 clnum, CAST(clnum AS int) AS clnum_int, clname1 
        FROM UsedNumbers
        WHERE ISNUMERIC ( clnum ) = 1 
            AND CAST(clnum AS int) >= @ModelNumber
        ORDER BY clnum
    )
```

and maybe use ISNUMERIC() in the first cte

Comment: It is obvious that it's a casting error, what I don't understand is why it works on one server, but not another, even though both are pulling the same data from our Accounting server (ELITE). Anyway, adding ISNUMERIC works. Thanks!

Comment: Execution plan can be different depending on the resources (CPU,RAM etc) or server settings (parallelism etc)